# NoClassDefFoundError for com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWManager

Tags: java, spring, maven, noclassdeffounderror, websphere-6.1

I have a Websphere server deployed on my machine and I'm getting back:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWManager`

This happens whenever I view any page on the application I have running on Websphere.  There were no issues compiling with maven, only on run-time do I have this problem.  I did some research and found this particular exception points to a problem with the class path.  Shouldn't this class come with Websphere?  Do I just need to point the class path to it?

Top two lines of the stack trace:

`[9/8/14 16:36:46:278 GMT] 0000007c SpringServlet I   Creating new child context from /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
[9/8/14 16:36:46:287 GMT] 0000007c ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet service: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWManager`

Comment: which version of spring and websphere are you using?

Comment: Websphere 6.1.0.41 and Spring 3.1.2

Comment: try this [solution](http://thysmichels.com/2011/09/07/org-springframework-transaction-transactionsystemexceptionuowmanager/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...Websphere did not fully update due to a permission issue on the folder, but claimed it was updated.  I reinstalled it to a different folder and ran the updates successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page [Using Spring and Hibernate with WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)
Try to use the following entry as transaction manager instead of UOWManager.